# Are Supercapacitors Polarized

Tags: polarity, supercapacitor, reverse-polarity

There seems to be conflicting information on the internet.

Are super capacitors polarized?  For instance, could you charge them and then suddenly invert their polarity (à la charge pump)?

Comment: Super capacitors are polarised.

Comment: A charge pump can be made with polarized capacitors.

Comment: wikipedia (shitty source i know!) article on supercaps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor   says "Supercapacitors are polarized and must operate with the correct polarity. Polarity is controlled by design with asymmetric electrodes, or, for symmetric electrodes, by a potential applied during manufacture." And charge pumps are not really inverting the polarity, the caps are switched to be in series giving a higher voltage. Maybe you mean inverting charge pumps for negative voltage?

Comment: @kyran even those can be made with polarized capacitors, check for unstance the max232.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen yes, i've used them in my designs. Although for PCB space I used non-polarized ceramic caps

Comment: This is exactly why I'm confused.  According to the Maxwell datasheet on their Ultra capacitors: "Unlike many batteries the anode and cathode of an ultracapacitor are comprised of the same material. If the positive and negative terminal and casing are also comprised of simila r materials, then theoretically the ultracapacitor has no true polarity."  http://www.maxwell.com/products/ultracapacitors/docs/1014627_boostcap_product_guide.pdf

Comment: @Kryan: Yes, I mean putting a super cap in an inverting charge pump.  It was just a use case example.

Comment: If a device consists of two identical porous carbon electrodes with an organic electrolyte solution, how can it be truly polarized? There is no significant faradaic that takes place and ions don't really need to cross the separator.
So I just don't see how these can be polarized???

Comment: I have a bunch of supercapacitors lying around and not one of them isn't polarized. It's probably the same your supercaps too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor):

> Supercapacitors are polarized and must operate with the correct
>   polarity. Polarity is controlled by design with asymmetric electrodes,
>   or, for symmetric electrodes, by a potential applied during
>   manufacture.

-

> Polarity
>
> Although the anode and cathode of symmetric supercapacitors consist of
>   the same material, theoretically supercapacitors have no true
>   polarity. Normally catastrophic failure does not occur, however
>   reverse-charging a supercapacitor lowers its capacity. It is
>   recommended practice to maintain the polarity resulting from a
>   formation of the electrodes during production. Asymmetric
>   supercapacitors are inherently polar.
>
> Supercapacitors may not be operated with reverse polarity, precluding
>   AC operation.

In other words, even for capacitors with symmetric electrode structures, there is a "charging" process during the manufacture that creates a asymmetric insulating layer inside the capacitor. You *can* reverse-charge a super capacitor, but doing so likely leads to a microscopic degradation of the specially prepared electrode surfaces (probably due to bizarre chemistry physics I don't understand), reducing the available capacitance.

I suspect this is similar to the process for manufacturing [lead-acid batteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93acid_battery#Electrochemistry), where the plates are actually initially identical, and the initial charging process modifies the chemical properties of both plates. In their un-conditioned state, it's probably possible to electrochemically convert either electrode to the "positive" electrode, but once the electrode have been conditioned, trying to reverse their polarization would probably damage their chemical properties, and thus the capacitor.